# Doctrine: Order by alias with same name as column

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I have following DQL (Doctrine1.2):

```
$dql->select('sum(t.column1) column1, t.column2')
    ->from('Table t')
    ->groupBy('t.column2')
    ->orderBy('column1');
```

But the generated SQL is same like for the following DQL:

```
$dql->select('sum(t.column1) column1, t.column2')
    ->from('Table t')
    ->groupBy('t.column2')
    ->orderBy('t.column1'); //Ordered by column1 not by sum(t.column1)
```

Is it possible to force Doctrine to use alias `column1` instead of the column name `t.column1`?

I need this, because I would like to have same output format from model for two very similar DQLs. (lately rendered by the same template). The other DQL looks like this:

```
$dql->select('t.column1, t.column2')
    ->from('Table t')
    ->orderBy('t.column1');
```

Possible workaround is to select `sum(t.column1)` twice. First with alias `column1` and second time with some other alias, why is after passwd to the `orderBy` function, but it's does not look like the clearest solution.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you try this approach? Just put the "sum(t.column1)" in the order by, instead of trying to use the alias:

```
$dql->select('sum(t.column1) as column1, t.column2')
    ->from('Table t')
    ->groupBy('t.column2')
    ->orderBy('sum(t.column1)');
```

Comment: This works, but generates `ORDER BY SUM(t.columnt1)` into SQL. Looks better than selecting column two times, but is this the best solution? Does SQL optimizer recognize it and count `sum(t.column1)` only once?

Comment: @Petr Yes, unless you're using some fairly crazy DB backend. That's a venerable SQL idiom and all the modern engines will recognise what you're doing and optimise correctly. MySQL will certainly be fine.